# Error with facebook login on 4g networks

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.forms, 4g

I am developing an application that requires logging in facebook and for this I am using the following code:

https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms

It works perfectly when I am connected to the internet via wifi, but when I connect through 4g I receive the following message and then the device stops. I really do not know what the error is, as with the wifi it works correctly.

[Evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvF93.png)

Facebook code is the same as github demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution and is that when you access facebook from an Android browser, you are redirected to:

https://web.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token= < access_token >

It is only a question of replacing the "web" with "www" in the url.